# How to extend AppCompactActivity and Fragment together?

Tags: java, android, class, interface, extend

As of now I have two classes, the first class is what I want to put inside the second class which works with fragments.

The first class looks like this -

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2_fragment);
        
}
```

and the second class looks like this

```js
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";

   

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_fragment,container,false);
       
        return view;
    }
}
```

I want to combine these but then I would need something like this

```js
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment, AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback {
}
```

I been looking everywhere but came to the conclusion that the only way of doing this the way I wanted is with an interface. But I would be with a similar problem implement two interfaces in one class! :( Please help I been trying to do this for 4 days already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to combine these" -- why? Since it cannot be done, if you explain a bit more what you think that you will be gaining, perhaps we can give you other suggestions for solving your underlying problem. "But I would be with a similar problem implement two interfaces in one class" -- a class can implement as many interfaces as is needed. I have written classes that have implemented 4-5 interfaces.

Comment: This stack thread might help<br>
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730189/how-to-extend-both-fragment-and-appcompatactivity-to-a-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

First off, a Fragment and an Activity are two very very different things.

Second, you literally can't extend from 2 different classes in Java. It's not possible.

Third, you're inflating the same view in your Activity as in your Fragment. This is probably not what you wan't.

You should take a look a look at how to implement Fragments inside an Activity. You'll need to access the FragmentManager (every Activity has one), and then add the Fragment into that FragmentManager.

Try and google it, there are plenty of guides around.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Java. Because multiple inheritance is not supported in Java.

But for Interfaces, you can do it. You can implement more than one interfaces in single class, There you can implement the methods defined in all those interfaces.