# How to extend both fragment and AppCompatActivity to a same class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, inheritance

I have a class.I have extended Fragment to this class because I used fragments when developing Navigation Drawer.

The code is below

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment  {

public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```

Now I want to add a image slider to that class.The code I used is this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
```

When I add this image slider code to the aboutSLFragment class the code will be like this(below)

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment  {

ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;


public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```

But this gives a whole bunch of errors.But when I extend the AppCompatActivity class the errors disappear except for one.Like this(below)

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment, AppCompatActivity
```

As I know we can't inherit two classes.So what should I do to resolve it? please help me? It would be greatly appreciated if someone corrects my code.

I've added an image slider to aboutSLFragment.java but there are some errors which I cannot fix.I'm new to android so please somebody tell me how to fix the errors.I've bolded the errors.

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;


public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewPager = (ViewPager) **findViewById**(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) **findViewById**(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(**this**);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(**this**);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(**getApplicationContext()**, R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}
```

}

Comment: Not possible `Java` doesn't support multiple `inheritance`

Comment: I now its not possible.I asked what should I do?

Comment: setup your `ViewPager` in `onCreateView()` and post your `Logcat` if any

Comment: hello Abu Yousuf i added the image slider but there are some error which i cannot resolve.Please i am new to android, can you check and tell me how to resolve.i bolded the errors.Have a look

Comment: I have edited your code.Posting **Error message** is helpful to find the problem quickly. Hope next time you will post code with some **Error Message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code. Problem was:

1. `findViewById()`. Activity already have `findViewById()` method so you can call it in Activity. But `Fragment` don't have this method. In `Fragment` you have to find a View by `View.findViewById()` method, here `View` will be the view you are inflating in `onCreateView()`
2. `new ViewPagerAdapter(this)`. To create a View you have to provide a Activity Context. Here you are passing `this` its your Fragment instance not Activity Context
3. `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` this method also takes a Context. `getApplicationContext()` is not available in Fragment. You have to call `getActivity()` or `getContext()` from Fragment to get Context of the Activity.

   ```
   public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

   ViewPager viewPager;
   LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
   private int dotscount;
   private ImageView[] dots;

   public aboutSLFragment() {
     // Required empty public constructor
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
   viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView .findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

   sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

   ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());

   viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

   dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
   dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

   for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

       dots[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
       dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

       params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

       sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

   }

   dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
               dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
           }

           dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

       }
   });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
     getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
    }

   }
   ```

Check this code.